# Join query with ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database

I need to do a join query on firebase using elasticsearch,
can anyone help me?

In particular I have two nodes, in the child node I have a field that is the id of the father node and I would like to have as a result all the fields of the father node.

How do I build my index in the code?

In adding, in my client I use elasticsearchclient,
here is an extract of the code to index a node:

```
var db = admin.database();
var etest = db.ref(type); 
etest.on('child_added',   createOrUpdateIndex);
etest.on('child_changed', createOrUpdateIndex);
etest.on('child_removed', removeIndex);

function createOrUpdateIndex(snap) {

 client.index(index, type, snap.val(), snap.key)
 .on('data', function(data) { console.log('indexed', snap.key + data ); })
 .on('error', function(err) { console.log('index error ', err); }).exec();
}

 function removeIndex(snap) {
  client.deleteDocument(index, type, snap.key, function(error, data) {
    if( error ) console.error('failed to delete', snap.key, error);
    else console.log('deleted', snap.key);
 });
}
```

And to take query results:

```
var queue = db.ref("search"); 
queue.child('request').on('child_added', processRequest);

function processRequest(snap) {
    console.log('process...... ');
   snap.ref.remove(); // clear the request after we receive it
   var data = snap.val();
   // Query ElasticSearch
    client.search(index, data.type, { "query": { 'query_string': {
            "query" : data.query
        }}})

   .on('data', function(results) {
       var res = JSON.parse(results);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(res.hits));
       console.log("TOTAL " + JSON.stringify(res.hits.total));
       queue.child('response/'+snap.key).set(results);
   })

   .on('error', function(error){ console.log("errore"); }).exec();

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't both the nodes have same data? You should focus on creating a proper nested mapping  (parent-child hierarchy)

Comment: You can tell me how to do it with an example,
I'm reading the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html,
But it is very synthetic thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to store your data.
First is creating a nested doc. This is helpful if you need to perform search on some of the values and need other info only for the display.

```
PUT /my_index {
"mappings": {
"yourIndex": {
  "properties": {
    "yourColumn": {
      "type": "nested", 
      "properties": {
        "name":    { "type": "string"  },
        "parentNode": { "type": "string"  },
        "childNode":     { "type": "string"   }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

Eg.

'str1', 'parent1', 'child1'
'str2' 'parent1', 'child2'

If you need not maintain any hierarchy,
you can simply create 3 separate columns and store like a flat data.

You can specify parent1 id and search for all the docs in both the cases.

Comment: Does this help ?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand.
To create the nested doc, how do I implement my code?